# I have an error with my return statements that I don't know to fix

Tags: c++, switch-statement, return

In a text adventure game that I am making, all the different places are run my different functions. In my diner, market, and supply store, I have a switch statement that takes numbers 1-10. All 1-9 work, but 10 doesn't. All of these methods return back to a method called `TownCenter()`, but on these 3, when I do return, you have to spam it in order for it to work. Here is a code example:

```
void Diner(){
    int answer;
    cout << "Blah, blah. Type '0' to go back to town.\n";
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer){
         case 0:
         return;
         break;
    }
    Diner()
}
```

Every time you type 0, it would just go to `Diner()` again. It eventually works if you spam 0 over and over, but why won't it work all the time?

Comment: You ask for `10`, but check for `0`? I recommend you replace `10` with `0` entirely, then see if you keep getting problems.

Comment: You're unknowingly using recursion each time they don't go back to town.

Comment: Why don't you print `answer` right after you ask for it, then make sure it is returning what it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any error with the code, except for the following considerations:

1. Missing semicolon after `Diner()` in line 10.
2. The `break;` statement is not required as `return;` is being used before it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean to use recursion here. I would suggest using while loops while people are in individual locations. By calling the same location again at the end of your case statement to go back to the same area, you are going deeper in the callstack, requiring more "exits" to "leave" the room.

A do-while loop like the following would work nicely:

```
int answer;
do {
    cout << "Blah, blah. Type '0' to go back to town.\n";
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer){
         // other case statements
         case 0:
             break;
    }
} while (answer != 0);
```

Notice I don't call `Diner()` again at the end. Getting it to process the same room until the "leave" is accomplished by the loop instead of unnecessary recursion.